Fourier coefficient of the hat function

I'm reading the paper ``Completeness in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$
of almost integer translates" by Alexander Olevskii (link).
In the proof of Lemma 1 in Section 4, the author claimed that the $\ell^1$-norm of the Fourier coefficients of the hat function $\max \{1-\frac{2|x|}{\delta}, 0\}$ is 1 for any $0<\delta<\pi$.
However, I computed the Fourier coefficients several times and kept getting the $\ell^1$-norm must be great than $\frac{2\pi+\delta}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ (where I used $\sum_{n\in
   \mathbb{N}} \frac{cos(nx)}{n^2}= \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi
   x}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}
   \frac{sin(nx)}{n}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$.)
Did anyone ever do the computation above and get the $\ell^1$-norm of the Fourier
coefficients of the hat function $\max \{1-\frac{2|x|}{\delta}, 0\}$ is 1 ?.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
Update:
I think the author in this paper used $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-inx}$ as the definition of Fourier coefficient instead of $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}$.
Let $f(x)=\max \{1-\frac{2|x|}{\delta}, 0\}$.
For $n=0$, we have $\widehat{f}(0)=(\sqrt{2\pi})^{-1}\delta.$
For $n\neq 0$, since $f(x)$. is even, we have \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\widehat{f}(n)&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^\delta_0 f(x)\cos(nx)\\ 
&=\frac{-4}{\delta \sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\delta}_0 x\cos(nx)+ \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^\delta_0 \cos(nx)\\
&=\frac{-4}{\delta \sqrt{2\pi}}[\frac{1}{n}x\sin(nx)|^\delta_0+\frac{1}{n^2}\cos(nx)|^\delta_0]+ \frac{2}{n\sqrt{2\pi}}\sin(n\delta)\\
&=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\sin(n\delta)}{n}-\frac{4}{\delta \sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\cos(n\delta)}{n^2}+\frac{4}{\delta \sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{n^2}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Then apply the summation formula above (note $\widehat{f}(n)=\widehat{f}(-n)$ if $n\neq 0$). We see that $$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}}\widehat{f}(n)+f(0) = \frac{2\pi+\delta}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$
I tried to verify this lemma because it is quite surprised to me that the $\ell^1$-norm of Fourier coefficients is totally independent of $\delta$

I can't access the paper right now. Just to be sure, could this be just a different choice of  $2\pi$-normalisation for the Fourier coefficients?

Questions should ideally be self-contained and not require access to an external source, especially if that source is paywalled (as this one is). As it stands, I'm not sure there's enough details from the original paper that an answer can be given. (For instance, what is the domain of their Fourier coefficients? The summation used suggests that it's over the interval $[0,2\pi]$.)

@Semiclassical Thanks for your reminder, I'll upload my work.

To simplify the work below, I'll use the unnormalized Fourier coefficient $\hat{f}(n)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\,dx$ and defer consideration of the normalization to the very end.
The basic issue is that the calculation proceeds as if $f(x)$ is nonzero on the interval $[-\delta,\delta]$. But in fact $f(x)$ vanishes if $1-2|x|/\delta \leq 0\implies |x| \geq \delta/2$, i.e., the interval of interest is $[-\delta/2,\delta/2]$. Hence symmetry in fact yields
$$
\hat{f}(n)
=\int_{-\delta/2}^{\delta/2}f(x)e^{i n x}\,dx
=\int_0^{\delta/2}f(x)\cos(n x)\,dx
$$
The case of $n=0$ is $\hat{f}(0)=\delta/2$ by inspection. Since I can't be bothered to work out the remaining coefficients by hand, I'll simply state that Mathematica yields
$$\hat{f}(n\neq 0)=\frac{8}{n^2 \delta}\sin^2\left(\frac{n\delta}{4}\right)$$
The key point for my purpose is that every Fourier coefficient is manifestly nonnegative, so the $\ell^1$-norm indeed amounts to summing $\hat{f}(n)$ over all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.
We could now proceed using the same summations as the OP, but here is an alternative method. Returning to the original form of the Fourier coefficient, the $\ell^1$-norm is given as
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_{-\delta/2}^{\delta/2} f(x) e^{i n x}\,dx$$ If we now blithely interchange summation and integration, we may use the Fourier series of the Dirac comb to write this sum as
$$
\int_{-\delta/2}^{\delta/2}f(x)\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{i n x}\,dx=\int_{-\delta/2}^{\delta/2}f(x)\cdot 2\pi \delta(x)\,dx
=2\pi f(0)=2\pi
$$
Hence the $\ell^{1}$-norm is independent of $\delta$, and if we normalize the Fourier coefficients by a factor of $1/(2\pi)$ we indeed obtain an $\ell^{1}$-norm of $1$.
There is one puzzling point, however: When $\delta=2\pi$, the hat function is confined to $[-\pi,\pi]$ and thus the arguments above seem to go through just fine. In other words, it seems as if the argument applies up to $\delta=2\pi$ not $\delta=\pi$. This suggests some factor-of-two error, either in the interval of interest or in the definition of $f(x)$, but lacking access to the original paper I can only speculate.

Just a few quick questions. 1. Shouldn't $\widehat{f}(n)$ be 2$\int^{\delta/2}_0 f\cos(nx)$? 2. When you used Dirac comb, how did you justify the interchange of infinite sum and integral here? What topology did you use here?

Also, if we use the mathematica Fourier coefficient above to compute the $\ell^1-$ norm, we can obtain the exact same result $\frac{2\pi+\delta}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ (use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sin^2(nx)}{n^2} = \frac{\pi x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}.$ )
